# Использование составного главного ключа в JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, jpa

**Имеется:** таблица с двумя колонками: одна содержит простые данные (INT), вторая - вторичный ключ, представленный INT-ом. Основным является составной ключ из двух колонок.
Код создания:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_foreignKey
(
    data INT,
    foreignKey INT,
    CONSTRAINT data_foreignKey_pk
        PRIMARY KEY (data , foreignKey )
);
```

В коде создан entity, соответствующий таблице:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_foreignKey")
@IdClass(DataForeignKeyCompositeKey.class)  // См. ниже
public class DataForeignKey{
    @Id  // См. ниже
    @Column(name = "data")
    private Integer data;

    @Id  // См. ниже
    @JoinColumn(name = "foreignKey")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ForeignType foreign;

    // ...
}
```

Класс `ForeignType`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "foreignTypes")
public class ForeignType {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    ...
}
```

Была попытка прикрутить составной ключ с использованием `@IdClass`: в классе `DataForeignKey` появились аннотации, отмеченные комментариями, а также был создан следующий класс:

```java
public class DataForeignKeyCompositeKey implements Serializable {
    private Integer data;
    private ForeignType foreign;
}
```

Программа скомпилировалась, однако при попытке записать в БД объект `DataForeignKey` Spring выдал мне ошибку следующего содержания:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set o.C.ForeignType field o.C.DataForeignKeyCompositeKey.foreign to java.lang.Integer`.

Я прошёлся отладчиком, и перед вызовом условного `dataForeignKeyRepository.saveAndFlush(dataForeignKey)` переменная `dataForeignKey` содержит правильный набор данных (то есть, `dataForeignKey.foreign != null`).

**Вопрос:** Что могло пойти не так? Можно ли воспользоваться `@IdClass` для решения такой задачи?

Comment: Судя по https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/id-class-with-many-to-one-relation.html поле `foreign` в `DataForeignKeyCompositeKey` должно быть `Integer`, т.е. это должен быть ключ из `ForeignType`, а не сама сущность.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, благодарю, ошибка ушла. Не мог никак выцепить подобный пример кода самостоятельно. Если перенесёте в ответ, отмечу, как верный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поле `foreign` в `DataForeignKeyCompositeKey` должно быть `Integer`, т.е. это должен быть ключ из `ForeignType`, а не сама сущность:

```
public class DataForeignKeyCompositeKey implements Serializable {
    private Integer data;
    private Integer foreign;
}
```

[Тут](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/id-class-with-many-to-one-relation.html) есть пример.